# iOS 9.3 How to use #selector for a method defined in subclass

Tags: xcode7, warnings, selector, swift2, ios9.3

I've multiple cells inherited from MyBaseCell class. In my ViewController class, I access those cells, type-cast them as MyBaseCell instance, and check if they respond to error label then assign error message to that label. It was easy using String literal in `respondsToSelector` method.

Here is my existing code in ViewController class giving warning.

```
let cell = cell as? MyBaseCell
if cell?.respondsToSelector("errorLabel") == true {
                    let errorLabel = cell!.errorLabel as? UILabel
                    errorLabel?.text = "Some Error Message"
                }
```

XCode 7.3 gives warning that No method declared with Objective-C selector 'errorLabel'. When I try changing it to `respondsToSelector(#selector(MyBaseCell.errorLabel))`, it gives error 'Type MyBaseCell has no member errorLabel', which is true as errorLabel is in some of MyBaseCell's subclasses.

Here is my new code in ViewController class giving syntax error.

```
let cell = cell as? MyBaseCell
    if cell?.respondsToSelector(#selector(MyBaseCell.errorLabel)) == true {
                        let errorLabel = cell!.errorLabel as? UILabel
                        errorLabel?.text = "Some Error Message"
                    }
```

Comment: Try this subclasses.errorLabel

Comment: I concur with Oleg; My selector statement looks like this "let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressed(_:)))"

Comment: This code in ViewController with be having different subclasses of MyBaseCell at run time. Subclasses will always be changing dynamically so can't use any specific subclass name.